# Clearing the text when `text select` release

Tags: javascript, jquery

I required a trigger, whenever the `window` text selection cleared. 
Finally I found this approach.

Using the same `id`, I have added multiple event handlers, but I am not sure my work is the best.

Is there a better way to do this?

```
 $('#tenderContent').on('mouseup', '.tenderdocument', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if ($.trim(window.getSelection().toString()).length) {
        $('#text').text(window.getSelection().toString());
    }

});

$('#tenderContent').on('mousemove', '.tenderdocument', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (!$.trim(window.getSelection().toString()).length) {
         $('#text').empty();
    }
});
```

[LiveDemo](http://jsfiddle.net/mx09jcay/5/)

Comment: Soo... this code works as it should?

Comment: in the `jsfiddle` i placed the sample code. that's not integrated. but my app, i did not get any issue. still the code may not such good!

Comment: Well for one it doesn't work when I change the selection without my mouse :(

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery `$.on();` event listener can use 2+ events in its event listener parameter and then let you specify which one through `e.type`. This allows us to shorten **a lot** of code. With that in mind, we can also shorten your `$.trim(window.getSelection().toString()).length` to be `$.trim('' + window.getSelection())` and assign it to a variable for use in our if's. We can then further simplify it by testing for `e.type` being `'mouseup'` and if it's evaluates to false, it has to be `'mousemove'`. And so we don't have nested if's, we can just use logical AND and OR operators to do something if it even has a value, and something else if it doesn't. That brings your code down to this:

```
$('#tenderContent').on('mouseup mousemove', '.tenderdocument', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  var selection = $.trim('' + window.getSelection());
  if ('mouseup' == e.type) {
    selection && $('#text').text(selection);
  } else {
    selection || $('#text').empty();
  }
});
```

That is a **major** cut off the amount that you had before. It also simplifies a lot of stuff to be fast and efficient.

Comment: Nice suggestion. It's good to highlight the changes you've made clearly. You explained that it was shorter, but it can be worth pointing out how you can put 'mouseup' and 'mousemove' together to make it the one function.

Comment: I just edited it lol. :( We'll just have to see if it gets peer reviewed then. :/